# Fixed Position Width

Tags: html, css, css-position

Well I am working on an small website.

However I have problem with fixed position.

My header is 770px in width. It contain a couple of elements with it.

position: fixed; works really fine, but when I resize my website to another screen size, something like 640x480 the fixed element (header) cannot be fully visible in width.

I want it to be fixed for scrolling but I want it to be fully visible in width, if user is on smaller screen and cannot see it completely.

Here is an example on an wordpress theme.

http://dvl-den.net/

Same problem is with my small project. Try to open that website on 640x480 (resize browser) and you'll see my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That website generates a horizontal scrollbar on 640 width, because the container (which is not fixed) is wider, so the browser puts the scrollbar. Can you upload your code to JSFiddle or similar?

Comment: @TomRoggero the issue is not the scrollbar, it's that the fixed header does not scroll horizontally with the page (it is fixed, after all), cutting off part of the menu on the right side.

Comment: @TomRoggero theres the website, its all the same as on small project :)

Comment: @sachleenm , does it mean that I will need to make separately width for 640 wide screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a solution with CSS only properties. I'd try having `position: absolute;` on my CSS, and playing around JavaScript (my example requires jQuery) like:

```
jQuery(function($) { // document ready
    var $win = $(window),
        handler = function() {
            // try not to overload browser, creating a throttle
            var throttle,
                throttleFn = function() {
                    // this is what happens on window resize
                    $('#header').css({
                        top: $win.scrollTop()
                    });
                };
            return function() {
                clearTimeout(throttle);
                throttle = setTimeout(throttleFn, 100);
            };
    };
    $win.resize(handler());
});
```

It doesn't work really "cool" in mobile, but it's widely know there are mobile issues with fixed headers in web apps (different than native). If you need I can update with a JSFiddle example.

Check demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/qaKT7/ (you can play around with that 100 value to get a better experience, and also use `.animate()` instead of `.css()` to make it look fancier)

Comment: Hmmm I did not understood very much here.
On absolute position I can scroll it but it's not fixed then...
And on fixed position, still no scroll horizontally.

Comment: The point is to create the "fixed" aspect by JavaScript. So you only set TOP property by Js instead of both TOP and LEFT as it does CSS by default.

Comment: it's the same. `$(document).ready(fn)` equals to `$(fn)` equals to `jQuery(fn)` ... I chose this one because it's less verbose and creates scope for dollar sign instead of global object dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving

```
min-width:770px;
```

or try with `media queries`

Comment: It's not about width, but about horizontal scrolling behavior when there is a DOM element with CSS `position:fixed`

Comment: oh sorry,bcs so many of have problem with width when giving position fixed and minimizing the site,

Answer (score 0):

I think there're two ways:

1. Changing the width "770px" to a percentage.
2. Detecting the pixel height of screen, then adjusting the width according to this.